# Android: how to detect when user clicks on GridView?

Tags: android

I would like to detect when users click the background area of the `GridView` (not on a `GridView` cell) - possibly they click the margin between the cells, or area to the right of the last cell (if the last row is shorter than the others).

`GridView.setOnClickListener` throws a Runtime exception which suggests that I probably want to use `setOnItemClickListener`.  Any suggestions on how to get click events on the grid background?

Comment: That's interesting. What happens if you set an `onTouchListener`?  Or for that matter, override `onTouchEvent()`?

Answer (score 0):

What I typically do when catching clicks on a (normally not clickable) view, is to specify this in the XML layout using:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="someFunction"
```

I've not done this for gridview, but as far as I know, it should be usable for any View(group).